# Conditionally styling multiband raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qml

I have three rasters (altitude, slope, and aspect) and I'd like to be able to merge them into one multiband raster (which I managed to do), and then style it conditionally with a QML, without having to use raster calculation.

For instance, colouring a pixel if its altitude, slope and aspect matches a set of parameters only, and having multiple rules controlling the layer's look.

Is that possible in QGIS?

Comment: It has been a month since your post. Did you manage to find what you needed? I would say the answer is yes, and that the way is as you suggested in your tags using a script and pygis but it is difficult to give an answer without more specific details on the output you want.

Comment: No, I didn't find a way to use styling to color a raster layer conditionally. To be a bit more specific, I wanted a pixel to be a chosen color if its three bands each fall into a set of predefined value ranges.
For instance, color that pixel blue if :
100 < RED < 125 &
50 < BLUE < 74 &
0 < GREEN < 14